# SelectList Issue on saving - "The value ... is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having problems trying to Save an Appointment using the following models.

Entity Models:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishDateTime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Outcome { get; set; }

    public virtual AppointmentType AppointmentType { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentType
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a DropDown List (Selectlist) to populate the AppointmentType in the view from a ViewModel.

```
public class BookAppointmentViewModel
{
    public SelectList AppTypes { get; private set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; private set; }

    public BookAppointmentViewModel(Appointment appointment, IEnumerable<AppointmentType> appTypes)
    {
        Appointment = appointment;
        AppTypes = new SelectList(appTypes, "Type", "Type");
    }
}
```

However when I click to save I am getting validation error message `The value 'General Appointment' is invalid` - Where General Appointment could be any selected AppointmentType.
How do I save the *AppointmentType* in the Appointment - rather than the AppointmentType.Type?

Comment: May be it should be made required

Answer (score 0):

A DropDownList can only send simple scalar values when the form is submitted. So all you can ever hope to get from the client is the Id that this dropdown is bound to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Appointment.Id, Model.AppTypes)
```

On the server you could use this `Id` to retrieve the corresponding `Type` property if you need it from wherever this information is stored (I suppose a database).